# Black screen when booting Ubuntu 16.04.5 with RX 470

Tags: amdgpu, nomodeset

Specs:
MSI B-250M Pro VDH
Pentium G4600
Msi Rx 470 armor oc
1 monitor via HDMI

I had Windows but wanted to make the switch to Linux but whenever I load a USB drive and I choose try Ubuntu without installing it goes to a black screen. I tried editing the commands with nomodeset but that left me without the GPU being utilized. Any ideas as what is the problem and a solution?

Tried Ubuntu 18 as well